# Import Datasnap Connector in Smart Mobile Studio

Tags: datasnap, smart-mobile-studio

I've got problem with Smart Mobile Studio: I want connect with datasnap server, I import datasnap connector ( Tools>Import Datasnap Connector...) but when I execute code it prodece message:

```
[INFO] Building project 'test'...
[INFO] Compilation successful [101 ms]
[INFO] Generating JavaScript successful [286 ms]
[INFO] Linking...
Resource file [$(DataSnap)\connection.js] not found
Resource file [$(DataSnap)\serverfunctionexecutor.js] not found
[ERROR] Linking failed: Error: Some resources (2) were not found
```

It's weird  because I work with that server in my HTML5 Builder projects, and Delphi apps, and everything works fine. How fix it (or configure SMS) and force to work properly?

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure DataSnap server to generate these JavaScript files. It is a server feature available in the New DataSnap Server wizard. Did you check the option? SMS needs those files.

Also article on website Smart Mobile Studio how to use DataSnap connector:
[Using DataSnap Connector Importer](http://smartmobilestudio.com/2014/12/20/using-datasnap-connector-importer/)